# Loop in Sidebar Done Incorrectly?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to add a "Movie Reviews" Section to the sidebar, but it's also altering my main loop.  Heres the Code I have:

```
//Movie All Reviews
function display_movie_reviews( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_category('movies') ) {
        $query->set( 'tag', 'movie-reviews' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'display_movie_reviews' );
```

It's displaying the reviews like I want, but the category page at `site.com/movies/` is only displaying only the reviews

here is the loop for the sidebar:

```
<ul>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
    <?php add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'display_movie_reviews' ); ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'sidebar-reviews', get_post_format() ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
    <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'index' ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

and `sidebar-reviews`:

```
<li>
    <a class="sidebar-thumb" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'sidebar-thumb',array('title' => "")); ?></a>       
    <div class="sidebar-text">
        <a class="sidebar-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <span class="sidebar-rating"><!-- rating here --></span>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `wp_reset_query();` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query

> This function destroys the previous query used on a custom Loop.
>   Function should be called after The Loop to ensure conditional tags
>   work as expected.